# How to make tableView reload if Session complete download Data for it?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates

My application fetching Data from URL. I use NSURLSession to download data asynchronously.
The Data will be rearranging and displaying in Tableview. So everything need to be ready on viewDidload.

The problem is , asynchronous mean Data preparation will be 1 second slower than what the speed of the main thread.

View loadded , Tableview got  0 data , and display 0 data.

1 second later, 2nd Thread running completion handler , and storing Data from internet into @property well.

But the tableView was loadded with NOTHING DISPLAY  , and it need to RELOAD.

- 1st Solution

Yes , I can fix this problem , i just call [self.delegate.tableView reloadData]; inside GDC main thread (which is inside completion handler)   BUT IT SEEM VIOLATING MVC PATTERN!.

- 2nd Solution

so i need to figure out the second solution , to Let ViewController implement delegate for its own Model , so the code inside GDC would be   *[self reloadTableViewData];* instead of *[self.delegate.tableView reloadData]*

and these -(void) reloadTableViewData will be implemented by the Viewcontroller

- the second solution Failed

unfortunately , my second solution failed with  *"unrecognized selector sent to instance Model"*

- my Question

1) the right solution to reload TableView with Asynchronous data URL fetching , how to notify and let view controller know " Your data was ready , reload it "

2) why my second solution Failed ? (whats wrong with my delegate ?? it seem the error cause from my delegate )

Here is , basic code test from my second solution , same error "unrecognized selector sent to instance ...."

Viewcontroller.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @class Protocol_Holder;

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController

 @property (strong ,nonatomic) Protocol_Holder* holderObject;

 @end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import "Protocol_Holder.h"

 @interface ViewController () <myDelegate>
 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 -(Protocol_Holder*) holderObject{
     if(!_holderObject){
         _holderObject =  [[Protocol_Holder alloc]init];
     }
     return _holderObject;
 }

 - (IBAction)ReloadButton:(UIButton *)sender {

     NSLog(@"Button Pushed");
     [self.holderObject reload_container];
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
      self.holderObject.delegate = self;

 }


 -(void) reload_Model{
     // this is where [self.tableView reloadData] should begin;
     NSLog(@"Enemy Reload Reload Reload Reload!!");
 }

 @end
```

Protocol_Holder.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 protocol myDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void) reload_Model;

 @end


 @interface Protocol_Holder : NSObject {id<myDelegate> delegate;}

 @property (weak,nonatomic) id<myDelegate> delegate;

 -(void) reload_container;

 @end
```

Protocol_Holder.m

```
 #import "Protocol_Holder.h"

 @interface Protocol_Holder() <myDelegate>

 @end

 @implementation Protocol_Holder

 -(void) reload_container{
     [self reload_Model];
 }
 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are `wrong` that everything need to be `ready` on `viewDidload` because `request` for `downloading` `data` will take its `own time` `depending` on `connectivity` by that time you `show activity indicator` `displaying message` that `Please wait as downloding neccessary data`.

`Downloading request` can be added in `viewDidload` method

Also your `tableView` should have `header` `displaying` `message` `no records`.

When `download completes` then you can `reload tableView` or if `download fails` then `alert user` by `displaying appropriate message`